# Is there any trick you can use to derive f( h(x),x)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I was just wondering, is there a way to derive
$ \frac{d}{dx} f( h(x),x)$ without knowing how the function looks? For example by some trick of using multivariable diferentiation of $f(h(x),y)$?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be looking for the chain rule.  Think of $f$ as a function of $y$ and $z$ evaluated at $y=h(x)$ and $z=x$.  Then

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(h(x),x) = h'(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(h(x),x) +\frac{\partial}{\partial z} f(h(x),x),$$

where $\partial f/\partial y$ denotes the *partial derivative* of $f$ with respect to $y$, i.e. the derivative of $f$ with respect to $y$ treating $z$ as a constant.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I got myself confused with naming variables.